# Proper Perl OO Inheritance

Tags: perl, oop, inheritance

I'm trying to create a child class of a custom module that we have in our code base. We have our modules in a directory that we include in all of our files. So we begin with

```
use Env;
use lib "$ENV{OurKey}/RootLib"; # All of our modules are here
```

Next, I have my parent module, located in `RootLib/Dir1/Parent.pm` whose code has been long standing, and so I'd rather not change any of it, but rather have the child be able to inherit from it as it is.

```
package Parent;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Env;
use lib "$ENV{OurKey}/RootLib";

sub new {
    my $proto = shift;
    my $class = ref($proto) || $proto;
    my $self = {};

    # Some other stuff

    bless ($self, $class);
    return $self;
}
```

At this point, I'm a bit lost, because I've seen a number of different ways to define the child constructor, but none have worked for me. This is what I have, but it does not work because subroutines that should be inheritied from the parent cannot be found in the child package. The child package is in `RootLib/Dir1/Dir2/Child.pm`

```
package Child;
use strict;
use warnings;
use vars qw(@ISA);
use Env;
use lib "$ENV{OurKey}/RootLib";

require Dir1::Parent;
push @ISA, 'Dir1::Parent';

sub new {
    # This constructor is clearly incorrect, please help
    my $proto = shift;
    my $class = ref($proto) || $proto;
    my $self = Parent::new($class);

    bless ($self, $class);
    return $self;
}
```

And then, in my test.pl file, I have

```
use Env;
use lib "$ENV{OurKey}/RootLib";
use Dir1::Dir2::Child;

my $childObj = Child->new();
$childObj->inheritedParentSubroutine( ... ); # Cannot find this subroutine
```

Comment: `Env` is a fairly dangerous module to use like that; I would recommend only using it with a limited set of includes: `use Env qw/ $PATH /;`, for example.  Also, you *don't* need to `use` it to access environment variables as `$ENV{OurKey}`; raw Perl has that ability.

Comment: `use Moose;` or one of lookalikes.

Comment: Notes: 1) That `use Env;` is useless. 2) `use lib "$ENV{OurKey}/RootLib";` should only be located in the script (.pl file), not the module (.pm file).

Comment: @el.pescado, Moose isn't an option. That would required more changes than should be necessary to get this to work properly. Same goes for `use Env`, @ikegami

Answer (score 2):

The parent class declares it is in `package Parent` (even if the file that contains it is `Dir1/Parent.pm`), so the child's `@ISA` should just include `Parent`.

Or you can work around your unfortunate directory structure with some additional `use lib ...` statements.

```
package Child;
use lib "$ENV{OurKey}/RootLib/Dir1";
require Parent;      # found in $OurKey/RootLib/Dir1/Parent.pm
our @ISA = ('Parent');
...

# test.pl
use lib "$ENV{OurKey}/RootLib/Dir1/Dir2";
use Child;           # found in $OurKey/RootLib/Dir1/Dir2/Child.pm
...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work because (by some decision that was made before my time) the directory that Parent.pm is in, has the same name as Parent.pm. So we have `RootLib/Parent/Parent.pm` and `RootLib/Parent/Dir2/Child.pm` I've tried `require Parent;` and it fails to find it.

Comment: So if you do `use lib "RootLib/Parent"; require Parent;`, it fails?

Comment: I misread your example. It seems inheritance doesn't like to search through directories to get to the Parents and Children. However, my issue now is that I'm getting `"Subroutine foo redefined at Parent.pm line xxx"`. I suspect this has to do with my Child's new subroutine.

Comment: Make no sense to have `use lib` in a module.

Answer (score 0):

The to-be parent class has `package Parent;`, but then you have `@ISA = 'Dir1::Parent';`. Those don't match, which is why the method can't be found. (That, and the fact that you didn't actually define the method anywhere!)

The file name, the name in the `package` statement, the name in the `use` statement, and the name in `@ISA` must all match.

What follows are two possible solutions.

---

### If the classes are named `Dir1::Parent` and `Dir1::Dir2::Child`

```
use lib "$ENV{OurKey}/RootLib";

use Dir1::Parent      qw( );
use Dir1::Dir2::Child qw( );
```

(Note that `use Env` was removed since it wasn't being used.)

`(.../RootLib/)Dir1/Parent.pm`:

```
package Dir1::Parent;          # Must match the file name.
use strict;
use warnings;

...
```

`(.../RootLib/)Dir1/Dir2/Child.pm`:

```
package Dir1::Dir2::Child;     # Must match the file name.
use strict;
use warnings;

use Dir1::Parent qw( );        # Must match the file name
our @ISA = 'Dir1::Parent';     #   and the package name.
   -or-
use parent 'Dir1::Parent';     # This can replace the other two lines.

...
```

### If the classes are named `Parent` and `Child`

Don't modify @INC (e.g. via `use lib`) in modules. Your script should contain the following:

```
use lib
   "$ENV{OurKey}/RootLib/Dir1",
   "$ENV{OurKey}/RootLib/Dir1/Dir2";

use Parent qw( );
use Child  qw( );
```

(Note that it's really weird to have a library directory inside of another library directory!)

`(.../RootLib/Dir1/)Parent.pm`:

```
package Parent;                # Must match the file name.
use strict;
use warnings;

...
```

`(.../RootLib/Dir1/Dir2/)Child.pm`:

```
package Child;                 # Must match the file name.
use strict;
use warnings;

use Parent qw( );              # Must match the file name
our @ISA = 'Parent';           #    and the package name.
   -or-
use parent 'Parent';           # This can replace the other two lines.

...
```

---

As for the constructors,

Parent:

```
sub new {
    my $class = shift;                # That proto thing is a bad practice.
    my $self = bless({}, $class);     # Don't need two lines to do this.

    # ...

    return $self;
}
```

Child:

```
sub new {
    my $class = shift;                # That proto thing is a bad practice.
    my $self = $class::SUPER->new();  # Don't need two lines to do this.
                                      # If you don't need to do anything here,
    # ...                             #   you can just inherit the parent's new
                                      #   by removing this sub entirely.
    return $self;
}
```